# Subsetting data based on variable name?

Tags: r, subset, limit

I am working in R. I have a large dataset (with over 700 'Name') a subset looks like this:

```
Name             Value

Harris           64
Harris           78
Harris           4
Jackson          102
Jackson          170
Drew             75
Smith            143
Smith            38
```

I want to write a function that flags values as outliers for each 'Name' based on a set of limits I have:

```
Name            Limit
Harris           0 - 70
Jackson          0 - 150
Drew             0 - 80
Smith            0 - 70
```

I want to say based on the limits, if any values fall outside of them, to produce a new table flagging those as outliers. I imagine this to be a new column with 'TRUE' for outlier, and example below:

```
Name             Value         Outlier

Harris           64            FALSE
Harris           78            TRUE
Harris           4             FALSE
Jackson          102           FALSE 
Jackson          170           TRUE
Drew             75            FALSE
Smith            143           TRUE
Smith            38            FALSE
```

If I were to do this with just one 'Name' I would use the `subset` function, but as I have multiple names that I have to match with my limits, I am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a limit table with `"Name"` and min and max of your limits, you could do a `left_join` on it and then check for outlier using `between`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  left_join(limits, by = "Name") %>%
  mutate(Outlier = !data.table::between(Value, min, max))


#     Name Value min max Outlier
#1  Harris    64   0  70   FALSE
#2  Harris    78   0  70    TRUE
#3  Harris     4   0  70   FALSE
#4 Jackson   102   0 150   FALSE
#5 Jackson   170   0 150    TRUE
#6    Drew    75   0  80   FALSE
#7   Smith   143   0  70    TRUE
#8   Smith    38   0  70   FALSE
```

You can remove the columns `min` and `max` later if not needed.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("Drew", "Harris", "Jackson", "Smith"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(64L, 78L, 4L, 102L, 170L, 75L, 143L, 38L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

limits <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Drew", 
"Harris", "Jackson", "Smith"), class = "factor"), min = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), max = c(70L, 150L, 80L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thankyou when I run it I am getting the error message: 
"Error in between(Value, min, max) : Expecting a single value: [extent=706]" do you know why this is?

Comment: @Issy Can you check the updated code now ? I am using `data.table::between` now.